# Splitting MySQL General Query Log by Clients

Tags: mysql, logging

I would like to know a solution to splitting very large MySQL general query logs by specific clients that have accessed the server.

Ideally a separate log will be created for each client.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would think that you could relatively easily achieve this using [MySQL-Proxy](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-proxy/en/index.html).

You'd have to put together a LUA script that would be able to differentiate your clients (username, DB Name, connecting host), and then log each one to a separate file.